# Unable to run chrome e2e on WSL

Tags: angular, protractor, wsl-2, e2e

WSL protractor e2e test cannot start chrome, and threw below error

```
 E/launcher - unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.   (chrome not reachable)
```

Answer (score 0):

Open protractor.conf.js

Update config and add ***'--no-sandbox'*** chromeOptions.args

```
 exports.config = {
    capabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome',
        chromeOptions: {
            args: [
                '--no-sandbox',// <= this argument here
            ],
        },
    },
 }
```